# Ruby - array with indexes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, indexing, each

how can I do in Ruby an array with indexes?
My custom from PHP is something like this:

> @my_array = [0 => "a", 3 => "bb", 7 => "ccc"]

And this array I want to go through **each_with_index** and I would like to get the result, e.g. in a shape:

```
0 - a
3 - bb
7 - ccc
```

Can anyone help me, how to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called hashes in ruby.

```
h = { 0 => "a", 3 => "bb", 7 => "ccc" }
h.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" }
```

Reference with a bunch of examples here: [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html).

Comment: @user705586: Out of curiosity, are you coming from PHP? I think that arrays and hashes are the same thing there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an array, you want to use a hash.  Since your indices are not sequential (as they would/should be if using an array), use a hash like so:

```
@my_hash = { 0 => 'a', 3 => 'bb', 7 => 'ccc' }
```

Now you can iterate through it like this:

```
@my_hash.each do |key, value|
  num = key
  string = value
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in ruby already have indexes but if you want an associative array with index of your choice, use a Hash:

```
@my_array = {0 => "a", 3 => "bb", 7 => "ccc"}
```